Autodesk APS - AggregatedView with RVT and DWG
I'm using AggregatedView with multiple RVT models with no issues on geolocation. But when using a mix of RVT and DWG, the DWG shows out of place, although in REVIT the link by shared coordinates shows it on the right place.
What are the configurations / options to make so DWG shows on the right place?

(FYI: I'm a developer advocate for Autodesk Platform Services)
What probably happens is that the DWG model does not contain enough information for the AggregatedView to be able to position it properly relative to the Revit design.
The other option you have is loading and aligning the models manually (without relying on AggregatedView), as explained in this blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.

When you post answers with links to resources with which you have an affiliation, you are expected to disclose that affiliation in the post. Please [edit] your answer to include your affiliation. Otherwise your post may be deleted. Please see How to not be a spammer

I was able to solve this issue by forcing all coordinates to be in meters on the AggregatedView. The problem was due to internal units in Revit to be in feet while C3D dwg was in meters.
Thanks to all inputs!
António
